# Cannot access url.searchParams Prerendering - SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit, prerender, urlsearchparams

I would like to make specific link from my page ( https://www.bizraport.pl/organizacje ) prerendered. My issue is that page uses (in both `+page.server.js` and `+page.svelte`) `url.searchParams.get` which makes an error:

> Error: Cannot access url.searchParams on a page with prerendering enabled

I do get that there is infinite number of urls which can be created with parameters. However in my `+page.server.js` there is added `export const prerender = 'auto';` and in `svelte.config.js`:

```js
prerender: {
  entries: ["/organizacje"],
},
```

So why isn't it intelligent enough, to just get page `/organizacje` and do not worry about any url parameters. If there is any it should be standard approach (without prerender)

Links about similar topics:

https://dev.to/marcdaframe/sveltekit-dynamic-routes-static-renderer-17dl

[How to use get parameter on sveltekit when use adapter-static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081698/how-to-use-get-parameter-on-sveltekit-when-use-adapter-static)

Tried to make prerenderer work with specific url. This url is based on parameters, however not the main one. It may be filtered by additional parameters.

Comment: How makes accessing the `searchParams` in `+page.server.js` sense, if the page is pre-rendered? Are you trying to update the potentially stale data of the pre-rendered version?

Comment: Page "https://www.bizraport.pl/organizacje" should be pre-rendered. And only this page. But for example:
https://www.bizraport.pl/organizacje?page=2
or
https://www.bizraport.pl/organizacje?kierunek_sortowania=true

Or anything else with any other parameter should ask server (+page.server.js) to provide proper information

Comment: I'm having the same trying to reach the same thing and I simply can't.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [comment from Rich](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4942#issuecomment-1128339141) explaining why search parameters cannot be used during the pre-rendering:

> When you prerender, you're writing files to the filesystem so that a simple webserver can serve them. Query parameters can't exist on the filesystem (both in the literal sense that `?` isn't an allowed character on all filesystems, and in the sense that the webserver will ignore them), so if you have a prerendered endpoint called `/api/posts/get` then it doesn't matter how many times you call it with different parameters, it can only be saved as a file once. The files need to have different paths (`/api/posts/[slug]`), or it won't work.

A way around this is to use `beforeUpdate`:

```html
<script>
  let myParameter = null;
  beforeUpdate(() => {
    myParameter =  url.searchParams.get('my-parameter');
  });
</script>

<div>
  <!-- Use `myParameter` -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing url.searchParams during prerendering is forbidden - **on the server**. As [written in the documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender-when-not-to-prerender), you can get around this by retriving the parameters in the client, using `onMount()`:

```html
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

let page;

onMount(() => {
  params = url.searchParams.get('page');
})
</script>
```